# C# Next key input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my own intellisense without using a listbox. I'm trying to make it so if they start typing in something and hit enter it will select what they had typed and replace it with the code. I don't know how to get the **next** key, only the current one. If you know Java, I'm trying to accomplish: String a = key.next();

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        #region Intellisense
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Y)
            {
                if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
                {

                }
            }



        #endregion
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to store these...

Comment: Are you going to reinvent code snippets? Visual Studio has this already.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how the keydown event works.  It registers the current key pressed and not released.  The input isn't buffered like console input.  It won't see the next key until it's pressed.  You can however use a switch block to check for whichever key is pressed.  Or if you need to you can use the PreviewKeyDown to trap certain keys before the KeyDown event fires.

Comment: I know KeyDown doesn't allow for the next key to be registered but how would I do that?

Comment: Look up a state machine.

Comment: And this is petty... but the `#endregion` inside the `if-statement` is bothering me...

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't get the next key pressed in C# because there isn't an input buffer it is easy to get the last keys pressed by reading the textbox from the current selection position.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    #region Intellisense
    if (textBox1.Text[textBox1.SelectionStart-2] == 'S')
    {
        if (textBox1.Text[textBox1.SelectionStart-1] == 'Y')
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
            {

            }
        }
    #endregion
    }
}
```